# Performance issues after PostgreSQL v12 upgrade

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-performance

Just upgraded our RDS instance to `v12.2` from `v11.6`, and we are seeing some of the queries are performing much slower than v11.6 instance. After the upgrade, we rebuilt the indexes using - `REINDEX TABLE CONCURRENTLY <table_name>;` and the index size reduced by 30% which is great, but the queries are running much slower now. What could be wrong here?

This is what we have:

- RDS instance `db.m5.2xlarge` (32GB + 8 vCPU)
- DB size ~600+ GB
- Using default parameters for both DBs, we haven't touched any of the config parameters
- Some of the tables we are querying have 100-400 million rows
- We use soft deletes and have `discarded_at` column in most of our transaction tables and that column is indexed

For example the following query on `v11.6` - `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM widget_references WHERE widget_id = 18871272 AND discarded_at IS NULL;`

```
Index Scan using index_widget_references_on_widget_id_and_referenced_widget_id on widget_references  (cost=0.57..6092.11 rows=1857 width=63) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (widget_id = 18871272)
   Filter: (discarded_at IS NULL)
 Planning Time: 0.081 ms
 Execution Time: 0.028 ms
(5 rows)
```

And the same query on `v12.2`:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on widget_references  (cost=62136.38..91132.86 rows=7506 width=120) (actual time=8721.495..8721.495 rows=0 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((discarded_at IS NULL) AND (widget_id = 18871272))
   ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=62136.38..62136.38 rows=7506 width=0) (actual time=8720.233..8720.233 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_widget_references_on_discarded_at  (cost=0.00..27752.19 rows=1501282 width=0) (actual time=8707.217..8707.217 rows=300156705 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (discarded_at IS NULL)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_widget_references_on_widget_id_and_referenced_widget_id  (cost=0.00..34380.19 rows=1501282 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (widget_id = 18871272)
 Planning Time: 0.077 ms
 Execution Time: 8722.766 ms
(9 rows)
```

Another query on `v11.6` - `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE document_id = '33873' OR family_id = '9332932';`

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on widgets  (cost=9.90..394.74 rows=96 width=1228) (actual time=0.046..0.058 rows=10 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((document_id = '33873'::text) OR (family_id = '9332932'::text))
   Heap Blocks: exact=9
   ->  BitmapOr  (cost=9.90..9.90 rows=96 width=0) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_widgets_on_document_id  (cost=0.00..4.58 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (document_id = '33873'::text)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_widgets_on_family_id  (cost=0.00..5.28 rows=95 width=0) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=10 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (family_id = '9332932'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.090 ms
 Execution Time: 0.083 ms
(10 rows)
```

And the same query on `v12.2`:

```
Gather  (cost=14858.28..2886284.75 rows=606143 width=428) (actual time=0.409..4.207 rows=10 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on widgets  (cost=13858.28..2824670.45 rows=252560 width=428) (actual time=0.072..0.077 rows=3 loops=3)
         Recheck Cond: ((document_id = '33873'::text) OR (family_id = '9332932'::text))
         Heap Blocks: exact=9
         ->  BitmapOr  (cost=13858.28..13858.28 rows=606143 width=0) (actual time=0.171..0.171 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_widgets_on_document_id  (cost=0.00..4.58 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (document_id = '33873'::text)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_widgets_on_family_id  (cost=0.00..13550.63 rows=606142 width=0) (actual time=0.148..0.149 rows=10 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (family_id = '9332932'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.094 ms
 Execution Time: 4.242 ms
(13 rows)
```

DB Versions:

- PostgreSQL 11.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), 64-bit
- PostgreSQL 12.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit

Comment: Did you run `analyze` on the migrated database?

Comment: what did you do after analyze?